# App development process for appexchange

Tags: appexchange

I have a concern.

I have signed up for partner community through creating NEW Salesforce org.
This org has Environment Hub enabled and the org has status Trail (valid up-to only certain period).

Need to understand, do i need to create different org for code development and packaging.

If it is, which kind/edition of org will be applicable.

Also need to understand, if we publish the application in app-exchange  through new org(Ques: which org?), how i am going to track which all customer has visited my application in app-exchange and which all has installed.

The app is going to be a free app.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a developer edition org to build your packages or an app.

The org where you have an environment hub enabled can help you spin a new developer org or you can spin one for free .

To find how many people installed your app you need to set up leads and campaign via the publishing console .